# Script loading: jQuery vs vanilla JS -- why a difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

Why does vanilla JS's `onload` work where jQuery's <s>`load`</s> `on` does not when it comes to loading scripts?

So...

`thisScript.onload=function` Event triggers as expected.

<s>`$(thisScript).bind({load:function` Event does not trigger</s>

`$(thisScript).on({load:function` Event does not trigger

JS `load` and jQuery `onload` *both* work fine when it comes to  loading

`thisImg.onload=function` Event triggers as expected

is the same as...

<s>`$(thisImg).bind({load:function` Event triggers as expected</s>

`$(thisImg).on({load:function` Event triggers as expected

...but not for scripts.

I'm aware of `$.getScript` but I'm curious about the above discrepancy.

**Question** Is there an event binding for jQuery that works for script loading?

The following test is revealing:

```
window.onload=()=>
    var thisSrc, thisScript, thisTest;
    thisSrc="testScript.js"; //See contents below
    thisTest="JS";
    //thisTest="JQ";
    
    if(thisTest=="JS"){
        thisScript=document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("script"));
        thisScript.onload=function(){
            alert("Event Triggered"); //EVENT TRIGGERS AND THE SCRIPT LOADS.
        }
        thisScript.src=thisSrc;

    }else if(thisTest=="JQ"){
        thisScript=$("<script>")
            .attr({src:thisSrc})
//          .bind({
            .on({
                load:function(){
                    alert("Event Triggered");  //EVENT DOES NOT TRIGGER BUT THE SCRIPT LOADS.
                }
            })
            .appendTo(document.head)[0];
    }
}
```

Contents of testScript.js:

```
alert("Script Loaded");
```

Both JS and jQuery successfully load the script.  It's just the JQ event listener that doesn't trigger.

Comment: in Jquery **.bind** is deprecated. Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @gaetanoM Thanks for that.  Great to know.  I tested again this time using `.on`, and the results are the same.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect your note. all `bind`s changed to `on` Thanks again.

Comment: @Terry are you referring to `.on("load", function(){})` (the approach documented on JQ) vs `.on({load:function(){})` (the approach I listed above)?  Both those approaches do work when, say, loading <img> elements, but both approaches fail when loading <script> elements

Answer (score 0):

Resolved -- issue is order of commands.

`src` needs to be defined *after* the `<script>` element is in the DOM and the listeners are assigned.

So this works reliably...

```
$("<script>")
    .appendTo(document.head)
    .on({
         load:function(){
              alert("Event Triggered");
         }
    })
    .attr({src:thisSrc});
```

Order of `.on` and `.appendTo` can be reversed, but have happen before `.attr`